# Custom form to modify only some fields of an EntityForm

Tags: 8, entities, forms

I generated an Entity following [this guide](https://www.droptica.com/blog/how-create-custom-entity-drupal-8/). Now I would like to create a custom form to modify only some fields inside a single entity.
I was thinking to create an action inside the controller calling a new/custom form:

1. I created the routing file to open the form with the specified path (I know I can also create an action inside the controller to open the form with a custom template)
2. I created the form that extends the main EntityForm:

   ```
   class DetailedForm extends CompleteEntityForm{
       public function getFormId() {
          return 'detailed_form';
       }

       public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state){
           $form = parent::buildForm($form, $form_state);
           return $form:
       }
    }
   ```
3. I put some lines of code inside the functions getFormId(), buildForm(), validateForm() and submitForm().

But in the end the result is an error:

> Call to a member function getEntityTypeId() on null in
>   \drupal\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityForm.php on line 79 #0
>   \drupal\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder.php(196):
>   Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityForm->getBaseFormId()

Any suggestions?

Comment: This is a typical error when you call an entity form without providing an entity.

Comment: @4k4 yep, but what can i do?

Comment: If my guess is right then the error message has nothing to do with the code you've shown so far. There might be something wrong with the route the entity provides or how the action calls the entity route.

Comment: @4k4 it's correct. i found the problem. I'm going to update and close the issue. thank you

Comment: @4k4 i updated my question with a new issue :/

Comment: fixed: i will put the code tomorrow!

Comment: Answering your own question is fine, but you should add these an answer and not edit your question. This is to help future users who may stumble upon this. Thanks!

Comment: @mpdonadio i updated the anwer, could you undelete it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Based on the comments on the question, I fixed my issue.

I created the routing path to call the controller:

```
mymodule.manage_detailed:
  path: '/mes-detailed/cp/{eid}'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\mymodule\Controller\DetailedController::manageAction'
    _title: 'Detailed'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

Controller:

```
class DetailedController extends ControllerBase implements ContainerInjectionInterface {

public function manageAction($eid) { 

    $entityForm = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
        ->getStorage('main_entity')
        ->load($eid);
    $finalform =  $this->entityFormBuilder()->getForm($entityForm);

    $render['form'] = $finalform;

    $render['#theme'] = 'manage_detailed';
    return $render;

}


}
```

Then I put inside the template all the form with:

```
{{ form }}
```

Because using only some fields inside the template didn't allow to save data.
And finally I create the submit function to define the redirect:

```
public static function manage_form_submit(&$form, &$form_state) {
        $url = \Drupal\Core\Url::fromUri('internal:/link-to-go');
        $form_state->setRedirectUrl($url);
    }
```

To call the submit function I used the alter form function inside the module file:

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

 //drupal_set_message($form_id); //to show id of the form

 if ($form_id == 'name_of_entity_form'){

    $form['name']['#type'] = 'hidden';
    $form['status']['#type'] = 'hidden';
    $form['new_revision']['#type'] = 'hidden';
    $form['revision_log_message']['#type'] = 'hidden';
    $form['field_n1']['#type'] = 'hidden';
    $form['field_n2']['#type'] = 'hidden';
    $form['field_email_']['#type'] = 'hidden';
    $form['field_nd']['#type'] = 'hidden';
    $form['actions']['delete']['#type'] = 'hidden';

    $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'Drupal\mymodule\Controller\DetailedController::manage_form_submit';

  }
}
```